# Deleting the last characters in the specific columns

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a sample text file with following columns

```
scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0_2 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0_2
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0_2   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0_2
scff1  20   25   aa_bb_c4_98_0_1   scff4   11  25   aa_bb_c4_13_0_1
scff6  16   61   aa_bb_c4_84_0_1   scff6   15  16   aa_bb_c4_84_0_2
```

I would like remove the last characters in the column 4 and column 8 like following using awk

```
scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0
scff1  20   25   aa_bb_c4_98_0   scff4   11  25   aa_bb_c4_13_0
scff6  16   61   aa_bb_c4_84_0   scff6   15  16   aa_bb_c4_84_0
```

I tried using following script `sed -i.bak 's/_[0-9]*$//' sample.txt` but it did remove the characters after the last underscore in 8th column but not in the 4th column. Can some one can guide me in achieving my desired output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub()` in `awk` to perform a substitution in a specific field.

```
awk '{sub(/_[0-9]*$/, "", $4); sub(/_[0-9]*$/, "", $8); print}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all you need is:

```
$ sed 's/_[0-9]\( \|$\)/\1/g' file
scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0
scff1  20   25   aa_bb_c4_98_0   scff4   11  25   aa_bb_c4_13_0
scff6  16   61   aa_bb_c4_84_0   scff6   15  16   aa_bb_c4_84_0
```

or if your sed supports `-E` to enable EREs (which I expect yours does since you're using `-i`):

```
$ sed -E 's/_[0-9]( |$)/\1/g' file
scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0
scff1  20   25   aa_bb_c4_98_0   scff4   11  25   aa_bb_c4_13_0
scff6  16   61   aa_bb_c4_84_0   scff6   15  16   aa_bb_c4_84_0
```

or as @GlennJackman pointed out in the comments, with GNU sed (the above would work with other seds too, e.g. OSX sed), it'd be:

```
sed 's/_[0-9]\>//g'
```

Comment: That's smart, but not exactly what's OP asked, not specific columns. +1 from my side

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yeah but given the input and what the OP had tried previously I don't think she actually cares about selecting specific fields.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/_[0-9]\>//g'`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's useful to store the result of a substitution in [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) :

```
$ awk '{$4=gensub(/_[0-9]$/, "", 1, $4); $8=gensub(/_[0-9]$/, "", 1, $8)}1' file
```

#### Output :

```
scff2 54 92 aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2 30 18 aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8 80 96 aa_bb_c4_24_0 scff8 14 42 aa_bb_c4_24_0
scff1 20 25 aa_bb_c4_98_0 scff4 11 25 aa_bb_c4_13_0
scff6 16 61 aa_bb_c4_84_0 scff6 15 16 aa_bb_c4_84_0
```

But @Barmar solution is smarter/shorter/lighter

Not in all `awk` implementations : not `nawk`, need GNU `awk` or maybe `mawks`

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk, everything ending in `_[0-9]+' removed:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/_[0-9]+\>/,"")}1' file
scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/_0_./,"_0")}1' file

scff2  54   92   aa_bb_c4_1024_0 scff2   30  18   aa_bb_c4_1024_0
scff8  80   96   aa_bb_c4_24_0   scff8   14  42   aa_bb_c4_24_0
scff1  20   25   aa_bb_c4_98_0   scff4   11  25   aa_bb_c4_13_0
scff6  16   61   aa_bb_c4_84_0   scff6   15  16   aa_bb_c4_84_0
```